# Spring data configuration for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am using spring data for storing and fetching records from the database. Initially the database was MySQL, but now I want to configure the same application for mongodb. Please the application resource properties for MysQL.

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Connection url for the database connection
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:27017/purchase_books

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Can anyone please tell the configuration changes in case of mongodb ?

Comment: There is a nice documentation about Spring Data for MongoDb in their site.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is an RDBMS and MongoDB is an Document Database.

Hibernate supports NOSQL Database in the form OGM (Object/Grid Mapper), Documentation on OGM http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.2/reference/en-US/html/

Refer the below example for Spring, Hibernate and MongoDB
https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/use-spring-and-hibernate-with-mongodb/

Moreover if you are using spring and if you want to remove Hibernate you can go for Spring MongoTemplate
Refer the sample in the below url
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/<database name>
spring.datasource.username= <username>
spring.datasource.password= <password>
```

#OR

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=<database name>
spring.data.mongodb.username=<username>
spring.data.mongodb.password=<password>
```